# consume items from a scala Iterator

Tags: scala, iterator, scala-collections

I'm confused about behavior of method `take` in trait `Iterator`. It seems that it doesn't consume items. Here is an example:

```
scala> Iterator(1,2,3)
res0: Iterator[Int] = non-empty iterator

scala> res0 take 2 toArray
res1: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2)

scala> res0.next
res2: Int = 1
```

Apparently step 2 consumes two items, but in step 3 the `Iterator` is still at first item. Looking at the implementation, I can't see any kind of copying or buffering, just a new `Iterator` which delegates to the underlying one. How could it be possible? How can I manage to really consume *n* items?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The iterator in question is defined in `IndexedSeqLike#Elements` ([source](https://github.com/paulp/scala-full/blob/2.9.0/src/library/scala/collection/IndexedSeqLike.scala#L54)). A [ticket was recently filed](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5002) about the the inconsistent behaviour of `take` across different iterator implementations.

To really consume N items, call `Iterator#next` N times.

You might want to consider using `Stream`, which is a lazy (like `Iterator`), but is also immutable (unlike `Iterator`).

```
scala> val s = Stream(1, 2, 3)
s: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[Int] = Stream(1, ?)

scala> s.take(2).toList
res43: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> s.take(2).toList
res44: List[Int] = List(1, 2)

scala> s.drop(2).toList
res45: List[Int] = List(3)

scala> {val (s1, s2) = s.splitAt(2); (s1.toList, s2.toList)}
res46: (List[Int], List[Int]) = (List(1, 2),List(3))
```

Comment: Thanks retronym, I see the point. What made me discard `Stream` was the lack of something like a "current item pointer" (by the way, maybe due to Java influence, something that one might expect in a so called thing). Now I see that I could get a "current pointer" with a sequence of `drop` and look at `head`. I will try again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys.

This is my solution to consume bunches of items from an `Iterator`:

```
  implicit def consumable(i: Iterator[_]) = new {
    def next(n: Int) = {
      (for (_ <- 1 to n) yield i.next()).iterator
    }
    def skip(n: Int) {
      (1 to n).foreach(_ => i.next())
    }
  }
```

any comments will be welcome.

Comment: To be consistent with return type the definition should be:
implicit def consumable[T](i: Iterator[T]) otherwise it returns Iterator[Any]

Answer (score 1):

You want to consume the items, `drop` them. Note that most methods called on an `Iterator` will make that `Iterator` useless for further use -- useless in the sense that behavior is undefined and subject to change.

Comment: `drop` is actually subject to the same inconsistency as `take`. `{val i = Iterator(1, 2, 3); i.drop(1); i.next}` returns `1`, not `2`.

Comment: @retronym Once you called `drop` on `i`, `i` cannot be reliably used anymore. Instead, you have to use what `drop` returned.

Comment: Good point. `{val i = Iterator(1, 2, 3); i.drop(1).next}` gives 2. Everything but `next()` and `hasNext()` (potentially) invalidates the original iterator; although those methods may return a *new*, valid, iterator. I look forward to your documentation contribution to clarify this.